# C++ invalid conversion from 'const char*' to char*

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. I have an exercise about constructor with const char* parameter.

```
class Book
{
private: 
   char* title;
}
public:
   Book (const char* title)
   {
      this->title = title;
   }
```

When I code the constructor like that, I receive error *cannot convert const char* to char*.
I tried using
`strcpy(this->title, title);`
then, it run, but I don't get the expected result.
Can anyone help me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: `strcpy(this->title, title);` is the right thing but you have to allocate memory to store the copy of the string.  Currently this->title points nowhere.  Maybe try strdup()  https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup  Just make sure you free it in your destructor

Comment: Jerry and paxdiablo are both right. Just to add another option: make the member variable const and use initialization instead of assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing an exercise, did the course you are following not explain what you are supposed to do?

I would guess that this is an exercise in *dynamic memory allocation* and what you are expected to do is use `strcpy` after you have allocated some memory so that you have somewhere to copy the string to. Like this

```
this->title = new char[strlen(title) + 1];
strcpy(this->title, title);
```

You need to allocate one extra char because C style strings are terminated with an additional nul byte.

But any C++ programmer who was doing this for real (instead of it being a learning exercise) would use a `std::string` as paxdiablo says.

Comment: thank you! I understood my problem. My exercise is to write a constructor, no requirement for using _strcpy_ but I don't know how to write without using it

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't let you easily change a `const char *` into a `char *` since the latter has no restrictions on how you can change the data *behind* that pointer.

If you're doing C++, you should be avoiding `char *` (legacy C) strings as much as possible. By all means take them as *parameters* if you must, but you should be turning them into C++ strings at the earliest opportunity:

```
class Book {
private: 
   std::string m_title;
public:
    Book (const char *title) {
        m_title = title;
    }
};
```

The one thing you *don't* want to become is a C+ developer, that strange breed that never quite made the leap from C across to the C++ way of thinking :-)

---

And, actually, if a given book is never expected to change its title, you're better off making it constant and initialising it, rather than assigning to it, something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Book {
    public:
    Book (const char* title): m_title(title) {};
    void Dump() { std::cout << m_title << "\n"; }

    private:
    const std::string m_title;
};

int main() {
    Book xyzzy("plugh");
    xyzzy.Dump();
}
```